# vectorized computation of many matrix exponentials

Tags: python, scipy

I have many 2-by-2 matrices, `A`, `A.shape == (2, 2, 7324)`, and I have to compute the matrix exponential of all of those. Unfortunately, `scipy.linalg.expm` only accepts one matrix at a time such that I'd have to loop over the computations,

```py
import numpy
import scipy.linalg

numpy.random.seed(0)
A = numpy.random.rand(2, 2, 7324)

out = numpy.array([scipy.linalg.expm(A[:, :, k]) for k in range(A.shape[-1])])
out = numpy.moveaxis(out, 0, -1)
```

Is there a way to avoid this loop?

*Edit:* The corresponding scipy bug: [#12838](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12838)

Comment: Did You looked at `numpy.apply_over_axes` or `numpy.apply_along_axis`? I tried such construction `np.apply_over_axes(scipy.linalg.expm, a, [0, 1])`.. but still strugled with some errors..

Comment: What speedup do you expect? Using Numba (includes reimplementing expm in Numba) there is a factor of 50 easily possible, likely more with a bit of optimization. Is Numba even an option? Is A really a C-contigous array? (7324,2,2 would be more efficient)

Comment: Numba is not an option. I looking for properly vectorized computation. I don't think that shape (7324,2,2) will be more efficient; depends on the algorithm really.

Comment: Than you are looking for a np.vectorize solution? Won't change anything regarding performance. The implementation of expm is here https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py You obviously can't get any significant speedup without using on any (C/Fortran/Cython/Numba) extension in this case.

Comment: It's not that "obvious" at all. If the implementation uses now or few conditionals, vectorization is often very easy and leads to great speed-ups, only using Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of SciPy release 1.9.0 (released in July 28, 22), you can pass `scipy.linalg.expm` an array where the last two dimensions are square—that is, an array with shape `(..., n, n)`—and it will compute the matrix exponential
in a vectorized fashion.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html).

Answer (score 0):

From glancing over the code, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py#L550-L595
it seems that it really only assumes a single matrix. Therefore, if you want to avoid a python loop, you'll need to extract the relevant parts and either cythonize or numpy-vectorize them yourselves. Only catering to dense matrices can make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code for the pade approximation. This is just for 1 array, you'll have to numpy vectorise/ cythonise it. or just use @njit from numba

```
def matrixexponen(n,a):
    q = 6
    a2 = a.copy ( )
    a_norm = np.linalg.norm ( a2, np.inf )
    ee = ( int ) ( np.log2 ( a_norm ) ) + 1
    s = max ( 0, ee + 1 )
    a2 = a2 / ( 2.0 ** s )
    x = a2.copy ( )
    c = 0.5
    e = np.eye ( n, dtype = np.complex64 ) + c * a2
    d = np.eye ( n, dtype = np.complex64 ) - c * a2
    p = True

    for k in range ( 2, q + 1 ):
        c = c * float ( q - k + 1 ) / float ( k * ( 2 * q - k + 1 ) )
        x = np.dot ( a2, x )
        e = e + c * x
        
        if ( p ):
            d = d + c * x
        else:
            d = d - c * x

        p = not p
    #  E -> inverse(D) * E
    e = np.linalg.solve ( d, e )
    #  E -> E^(2*S)
    for k in range ( 0, s ):
        e = np.dot ( e, e )
    return e
```